# Click event URL to open another page in asp.net MVC using javascript/Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to click on the event on the Calendar (I'm using a fullcalendar plugin) and get redirected or open a Details view page in asp.net MVC related to this eventID using javascript/Jquery, so that the code will give the same URL to all events? Fullcalendar is integrated into asp.net mvc.

I wrote this code, but it didn't work:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    window.location = "<%= Url.Action("Details", "ReservationRequests", new { id = 
 Model.ID})
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes its possible. but first you should try something.

Comment: I tried the eventClick function, but it didn't work, giving an exception error. I edited my question to post the code. Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code for redirecting missing the closing `";`

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventClick: function() {
            window.location = "<%= Url.Action("Details", "ReservationRequests", new { id = Model.ID})%>";
        }
    });
});
```

Where calendar is the id of the div.

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, could you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: This is the exception details:
`Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`